# How to create links for certain parts of an image?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an image of a human body where I should make all organs like eyes, nose and ears clickable to link to different webpages. Is this possible out-of-the-box with HTML and/or JavaScript?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/map

Comment: @Ruddy, he never asked us to write any code - his question was: " i just want to know whether it is really possible through some software or through any different coding.? "

Comment: In answer to your question - yes, it's possible by using relative and absolute positioning, you can read up on positioning here: http://learnlayout.com/position.html

With this it's possible to define a left/top/bottom/right offset against the relatively positioned parent by using absolute positioning on a link attribute against an image attribute (link would be absolute, image would be relative).

Comment: @Jackhardcastle "how to create links or divs for a part of image?" to me that implies that they would like some code. If not then then you can forget that bit of my comment and move tot he part where this question is not suited for this website.

Comment: @Ruddy, he asked how this would be possible - see my comment as an example of an answer that suffices this question. Furthermore, appending a question mark to a paraphrased quote doesn't quantify a 'question' in my eyes..

Comment: @Jackhardcastle I think you have missed the point. I know this is possible hence my first comment saying "Yes this is possible". The point of my comment is that this question is not suitable for this website. I haven't said this question cannot be answered as it can and has been via the comments only.

Comment: @Ruddy, this question is fine for this website - he just wanted pointing in the right direction.

Comment: @Jackhardcastle I have posted this on [**Stackoverflow Meta**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287968/is-this-question-suitable-for-so-or-should-it-be-closed#287969) as you have made me question my actions against this question.

Answer (score 2):

Try using [image maps](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp).

For example:

```html
<img src="http://www.w3schools.com/tags/planets.gif" width="145" height="126" alt="Planets" usemap="#planetmap">

<map name="planetmap">
  <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,82,126" href="http://www.w3schools.com/tags/sun.htm" alt="Sun">
  <area shape="circle" coords="90,58,3" href="http://www.w3schools.com/tags/mercur.htm" alt="Mercury">
  <area shape="circle" coords="124,58,8" href="http://www.w3schools.com/tags/venus.htm" alt="Venus">
</map>
```

Comment: My reputation restricted me from commenting. I didn't see any comment about image maps before I answered. So I didn't vote any comments.

Comment: @kiran: Now it's actually an answer instead of just a link, as it should have been from the start, that's no longer a concern. BTW: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280478/why-not-w3schools-com